Decorating verbatim text in OpTeX
I want to decorate listings with a border and background color.
Specifically I would like a similar appearance to this:

How can this be achieved?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a short compilable teX code you have so far?

This is pretty close to Chapter 2 of the OpTeX manual:



The above is implemented in optex-techdoc.tex, so we can easily adapt it to work with Python:
% Initialization
\fontfam[lm]
\nopagenumbers

% Define the Python highlighter
\load[doc]

\eoldef\printpythonfile#1{{%
    \hisyntax{python}%
    \vitt{#1.py}%
    \verbinput (-) #1.py
}}

% Print the Python file
\printpythonfile \jobname % Replace with the name of the file you want to print

\bye



Thank you! I completely missed that the listings in the doc had this style.
